# Uncaught Error: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I have tried 4 react google map packages by now and all fail, so I want to just use google maps directly. I am getting `Uncaught Error: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child.`

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import GMap from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

var initialCenter = { lng: -90.1056957, lat: 29.9717272 }

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <GMap initialCenter={initialCenter} />,
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

components/app.js

```
import React from 'react';


class GMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = { zoom: 10 };
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="GMap">
              <div className='GMap-canvas' ref="mapCanvas"></div>
          </div>
        )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // create the map, marker and infoWindow after the component has
    // been rendered because we need to manipulate the DOM for Google =(
    this.setState({ map: this.createMap() })
  }

  createMap() {
    let mapOptions = {
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
      center: this.mapCenter()
    }
    return new google.maps.Map(this.refs.mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  }

  mapCenter() {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(30.3, -97.75);
  }
}
```

Comment: try to add a child to `<GMap initialCenter={initialCenter} /><p>stuff</p></GMap>` like this ! and tel me if the problem persist or not

Comment: yes i get same error `Uncaught Error: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child`

Comment: I gave up and built one from scratch. Very dissapointing docs/examples out there nowadays, poor javascript